# Error parsing json on mule ESB

Tags: java, mule, esb

Two days ago, my application worked fine, but now when I tested I receive an error and don't know what the problem is. Knowing that nothing is changed in the application. So my application is listening on a port and waiting for json data and then taking this json and sending it to a web service which will send a response.

This is a snippet of my code:

```xml
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json" path="getDetails" />
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
<set-session-variable variableName="tkn" value="#[message.payload.token]" doc:name="token" />
<set-session-variable variableName="msg" value="#[message.payload.msg]" doc:name="message" />
<component doc:name="Java" class="Transformer">
    <method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="methhod" />
    </method-entry-point-resolver>
</component>
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
<logger message="&quot;I can get properties this is app&quot;+#[message.payload.application]+&quot;this is the type&quot;+#[message.payload.type]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://slice.ws.com/api.php/push/send_test_push" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST">
    <set-property propertyName="application" value="#[message.payload.application]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="token" value="#[sessionVars['tkn']]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="user" value="#[message.payload.user]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="type" value="#[message.payload.type]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="message" value="#[sessionVars['msg']]" doc:name="Property" />
</http:outbound-endpoint>
<response>
    <http:response-builder status="200" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder" />
</response>
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
<logger message="&quot;result&quot;#[message.payload.success]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
```

### Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Transformer {
    JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject();
    public JSONObject methhod(HashMap <String, String> s) {
        Map <String, String> studentGrades = s;
        Iterator <Map.Entry <String, String>> iterator = studentGrades.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry <String, String> studentEntry = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(studentEntry.getKey() + " :: " + studentEntry.getValue());

            finalObj.put(studentEntry.getKey(), studentEntry.getValue());

            // iterator.remove();
        }

        System.out.println("json" + finalObj);

        return finalObj;
    }
}
```

### Error

```
ERROR 2015-04-13 10:34:47,458 [[applipush].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to "java.lang.Object"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@396e2b; line: 1, column: 2] (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser:1433 (null)
2. Failed to transform from "json" to "java.lang.Object" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject:132 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@396e2b; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I'm testing the application by sending this json via postman:

```
{
    "application": "91",
    "token":"APA91bEkK-ghBivQRIm7Rs1HfvmXPZ4i7XpcYMA5NGpN4orsqT",
    "user": "1",
    "type": "Android",
    "msg": "rajeun"
}
```

Comment: *Two days ago, my application worked fine, but now when I tested I receive an error* - Any changes between these commits? Any updates of libs? Also please show the output of your `System.out.println` in your code.

Comment: application :: 91
token :: APA91bEkK-ghBivQRIm7Rs1HfvmXPZ4i7XpcYMA5NGpN4orsqT
user :: 1
type :: Android
msg :: rajeun
json{"msg":"rajeun","application":"91","type":"Android","user":"1","token":"APA91bEkK-ghBivQRIm7Rs1HfvmXPZ4i7XpcYMA5NGpN4orsqT"}

Comment: The probleme is with the second json to object when i receive the response of the web service which is: {"success":0,"failed":1} i want to get the variable seccess and failed and do a test with this result this is why i used json to object it worked well but now ..

Comment: Please update your answer with the output

Comment: Thank you for help and for your time i think that there is a probleme with the web service. i'll update you.

Comment: There are many JSON to Object transformers in there, have you debugged to see which one is the one failing?

Comment: @afelisatti the problem was with the second json to object because of the web service it didn't return a json but now everything working well thank you everybody.

Comment: @Rajeun Either close this question, as it was a transient failure of a remote system, or post an answer and accept it, just don't leave it dangling like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the web service who send data other than json.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix  i hope it will work for you if not please let me know.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json" path="getDetails" />
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
<set-session-variable variableName="tkn" value="#[message.payload.token]" doc:name="token" />
<set-session-variable variableName="msg" value="#[message.payload.msg]" doc:name="message" />
<component doc:name="Java" class="Transformer">
    <method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="methhod" />
    </method-entry-point-resolver>
</component>
<logger message="&quot;I can get properties this is app&quot;+#[message.payload.application]+&quot;this is the type&quot;+#[message.payload.type]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://slice.ws.com/api.php/push/send_test_push" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST">
    <set-property propertyName="application" value="#[message.payload.application]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="token" value="#[sessionVars['tkn']]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="user" value="#[message.payload.user]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="type" value="#[message.payload.type]" doc:name="Property" />
    <set-property propertyName="message" value="#[sessionVars['msg']]" doc:name="Property" />
</http:outbound-endpoint>
<response>
    <http:response-builder status="200" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder" />
</response>
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />

<logger message="&quot;result&quot;#[message.payload.success]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /> 
<json:object-to-json-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="Object to JSON" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your code is correct and also mine but the probleme was with the web service which sent data other then Json.